# $\sigma$-algebra subset of another $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am having some troubles with $\sigma$-algebras.

Let $(X_n)_{n\geq1}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra with respect to the filtration $\underline{\mathcal{A}}=(\mathcal{A}_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $\mathcal{B}_n=\sigma(X_1,\dots,X_n)$.

I want to show that $\mathcal{B_n}\subset\mathcal{A_n}$. Intuitively it makes very much sense I think since $B_n$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X_1,\dots,X_n$, and $X_n$ is $\mathcal{A}_n$-measurable, thus $\mathcal{A}_n$ should contain more information. But how does one formalize it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of $X_1,X_2,..,X_n$ is measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal A_n$ because $X_i$ is measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal A_i$ and $\mathcal A_i \subset \mathcal A_n$. $\mathcal B_n$ is the smallest sigma algebra w.r.t. which each of $X_1,X_2,..,X_n$ is measurable so it is contained in $\mathcal A_n$.